# Rendering 3D shapes on a voxel

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, voxel

I have a 3D shape (primitive shapes like cuboid, sphere, pyramid etc.). The shape is described by a set of necessary geometric parameters. For example, for a cube, I have information about the vertices, dimensions and orientation of the cube. Now, I have a [voxel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) (kind of 3D grid of pixels). How can I determine which cells of the voxel needs to be filled and which will remain empty for "rendering" the cube in 3D?

Are there existing libraries for the same? Or, can someone point out the approach/algorithm that would help in this task? Also, what is this process exactly called, so that I can search on the Internet in the right direction?

Comment: [Rasterisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation)

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to render these 3D shapes as voxels instead of regular 3D graphics (GPU rendering with polygons, which does rasterisation internally)? If I had an idea of the end goal I might be able to suggest something more appropriate, as 3D volume rasterization might be trickier than you think.

Comment: @TimothyShields I need it to determine the number of cubes needed to cover the 3D shape. This number is the basis for determining [box-counting dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) for a shape.

Answer (score 2):

It is called "Mesh to Voxel conversion" or "Mesh voxelization" or to be a bit more general "Volume Visualization".

If you are interested in math here is some good articles about it:

[cs.swansea.ac.uk/~csmark/PDFS/cgfvoxel.pdf](http://cs.swansea.ac.uk/~csmark/PDFS/cgfvoxel.pdf)
[Complete Polygonal Scene Voxelization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.6993)
[Ray Cast Methods](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/powwie/p1/ray-cast.htm)